# Format / Indent c++ as you type inside expressions

Tags: indentation, formatting, filetype-c++

In visual studio, that code :

```
for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
{}
```

becomes that code :

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{

}
```

as soon as you hit enter.
I was wondering, is it possible, and if so, how can I make so vim does the same ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware of two possible approaches from within Vim.

#### On the fly formatting

My C and C++ snippets defined in [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/) (as abbreviations) and in [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template)+lh-cpp (as more *traditional* snippets) are expanded according to the current stylistic preferences (through another plugin: [lh-style](https://lh-style.readthedocs.io/en/latest)).

**Pros**:

- The correct style is used from the start
- No external dependences (clang-format)

**Cons**:

- The formatting possibilities won't be as rich as what clang-format offers (indeed, everything has to be rewritten in ... vim script) -- BTW, I haven't implemented extra spaces around semi-colons in lh-style (and I don't see the option in clang-format either... :/)
- Multiple Vim dependences
- Depends on a snippet engine which is not the one 99% of Vim users use -- yet my C++ snippets are quite advanced sometimes, and I try to provide as C++ idiomatic snippets as possible

#### On demand/retroactive formatting

Another approach consists in fixing the style every time some specific keys (or even ENTER, IIRC) are triggered. This is the [approach presented by Telno](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20632/626) that relies on clang-format.

**Pros**:

- The formatting shall be close to perfection
- Require a single vim plugin

**Cons**:

- Depends on an external tool
- The formatting is applied retroactively on code already written

Answer (score 1):

I used the plugin https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format.git
and added those lines to my vimrc :

```
" Clang formater things :
let g:clang_format#style_options = {
            \ "BreakBeforeBraces" : "Allman",
            \ "AccessModifierOffset" : -4,
            \ "AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine" : "true",
            \ "AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations" : "true",
            \ "Standard" : "C++11"}

" map to <Leader>cf in C++ code
autocmd FileType c,cpp,objc nnoremap <buffer><Leader>cf:<Cu>ClangFormat<CR>
autocmd FileType c,cpp,objc vnoremap <buffer><Leader>cf :ClangFormat<CR>
" if you install vim-operator-user
autocmd FileType c,cpp,objc map <buffer><Leader>x <Plug>(operator-clang-format)
" Toggle auto formatting:
nmap <Leader>C :ClangFormatAutoToggle<CR>
```

Comment: Your spacing is wrong and you're missing a `-` there: `<Leader>cf :<C-u>ClangFormat<CR>`. Do you need the `<C-u>` for the normal mode mapping? Visual mode is the one that adds `:'<,'>` implicitly... Also, usually you'd use `<LocalLeader>` for a `<buffer>` mapping.